# Sounds for build error/success in Visual C++?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

On long Visual C++ builds, it would be really helpful to hear some sort of (optional) sounds for such build/compile results as:

- individual compile error
- file compile success/failure
- build success/failure
- batch build success/failure

Does anyone know how to enable sounds for these kinds of build occurrences in Visual C++ (especially Visual C++ 2008 on Vista)?

Comment: Anyone why this has down-votes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CJM is almost right.

In VC++ 9 (Visual Studio 2008) Go to Control Panel's Sounds applet (Control Panel/Hardware and Sounds/Sounds in Vista).

Under the Sounds tab scroll to "Build Succeeded" under "Microsoft Visual Studio" and set a sound for this event.

If you have (or had) multiple VS on this PC (I have 6.0, 2003, 2005, and 2008) there may be multiple entries with names like "Microsoft Developer" or blanks - which I assume work in the older versions. I often end-up setting the wrong ones. It seems you'll have to close VS 2008 and reopen for this to take effect.

Someone mentioned this was broken/removed in VS 2005 - I noticed this as well.

Comment: This works and provides sounds for: 1) breakpoint hit 2) build canceled 3) build failed and 4) build succeeded.  For batch builds, fail/success sounds happen after the LAST configuration builds.

Answer (score 5):

Go to Start | Settings | Control Panel | Sounds, click the Sounds tab, and customize the entries under Microsoft Developer.

Comment: yes, I'm asking how to enable (not author) sounds.  Thanks, I'm going to try your suggestion.  I'm on Vista so I think the steps are similar but slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

In VS2005, the sound subsystem wasn't working correctly, not sure it was fixed in 2008.  Using macros, you COULD play sounds, like different ones for builds that succeeded, and builds that failed, however the person that I knew that did them was constantly crashing due to the macros failing.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to install the [Visual Studio Power Toys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2005/aa718340.aspx).  This includes a feature called 'Toast' that shows a notification in your system tray when a build has finished.  You might see if this has options that would be useful for sound notification.